# User input on TextArea control

Tags: model-view-controller, textarea

We have a **TextArea** control in our application where user has to enter the SalesOrderNumber one by one. But, some of the user giving the input in single line instead of one by one without any separator and it would lead difficulties while splitting the data.

Is there any control available in MVC application to enter multiple SalesOrderNumber one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to think a little differently. You can add a "plus" button, and grab all entries with multiple TextFields instead of TextArea. But, if you want to keep the textArea, in your controller you need to do the Split correctly, putting all possible cases, like, if the entries are separated by space, dash, comma, etc.

Using VRaptor MVC Framework, you can easily achieve this in java with the functions of the String class and/or split functions, so there is no need to change your View or Model layer.